# Scrolling (left/right when mouse touch borders) behaviour like Windows 8 but with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I like the way we can "scroll" on Windows 8 Start Page: we simply had to touch left or right borders of the screen, then the display is moving. Do you see what I mean?

Is there a way to reproduce this behaviour with jQuery?

So when I move my mouse cursor on the right border of the page, the page is scrolling automatically to the right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** proof of concept:

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/obocen/4/edit)

Sure you can:

- you need to know the width of your element
- apply overflow hidden to it
- track the `mousemove` inside the element `offset`
- use the `scrollLeft` **direction** `-=15` `+=15` animation if mouse is inside a "hot spot"
- animate like `.stop().animate({scrollLeft: direction },200, 'linear', loop);` (where `loop` is your function name callback)

jQuery:

```
var direction = '';
function loop(){
  $('#movable').stop().animate({scrollLeft: direction },200,'linear',loop);
}

var movableW = $('#movable').width();
  
$('#movable').on('mousemove',function( e ){

  var ofs = $(this).offset();
  var pos = {X: e.pageX-ofs.left};
  
  if( pos.X < 20){
     direction = '-=20';
     loop();
  }else if(pos.X > movableW-20){
     direction = '+=20';
     loop();
  }else{
     $(this).stop();
  }

}).on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).stop(); 
});
```